# Wordpress - Sanitize AROUND shortcode

Tags: wordpress, tinymce, shortcode

I have a [Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/checklist/) which allows users to mark a bullet list and then add a shortcode around it. Unfortunately, when users select the bullet list, the first UL is not selected and therefore they end up with a weird selection. The end code should be:

```
[checklist-box title="Hello"]
<ul>
    <li>xxxx</li>
    <li>yyyy</li>
    <li>zzz</li>
</ul>
[/checklist-box]
```

but instead ends up as something like:

```
<ul>
    <li>[checklist-box title="Hello"]
<ul>
    <li>xxxx</li>
    <li>yyyy</li>
    <li>zzz</li>
</ul>
[/checklist-box]</li>
</ul>
```

which looks horrible.

Clarify: I need the [checklist-box] shortcode to wrap the whole list including the

This is the code that wraps the bullets in TinyMCE:

```
onsubmit: function(e) {
      var selected_text = editor.selection.getContent();
      shortcode = '[checklist-box title="' + e.data.title + '"]' + selected_text + '[/checklist-box]';
      editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcode);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code,
Replace your onsubmit code with

```
onsubmit: function(e) {
                    var wholeText = editor.getContent();
                    var selected_text = editor.selection.getContent();

                    shortcode = '[checklist-box title="' + e.data.title + '" extraTitle="' + e.data.extraTitle + '" extraUrl="' + e.data.extraUrl + '"]' + selected_text + '[/checklist-box]';

                    var main = wholeText.replace(selected_text,shortcode);
                    editor.execCommand('mceSetContent', 0, main);
                }
```

Then let me know the result.

Comment: Sorry but this does not make any difference. The same code is generated.

Comment: Hi,checklist I have edited your plugin's  code into my local setup with my code. and it works for me .